# PHP Regex prefix with image file extension

Tags: php

I want to display all files with prefix: **`7ws9xfD1RHVaUPXh37NB_`** also it must have a file extension of `.jpg, .png, .gif`

These are sample strings:

```
7ws9xfD1RHVaUPXh37NB_Magnifying_glass_icon.png
7ws9xfD1RHVaUPXh37NB_url.gif
54a8sx555a4rrgsaBwzQ_korea.jpg
7ws9xfD1RHVaUPXh37NB_6780969-cool-abstract-wallpaper.png
7ws9xfD1RHVaUPXh37NB_wall_1409747331_multicolor-geometric-shapes.jpg
```

I've used this regex but no luck:

```
$key  "7ws9xfD1RHVaUPXh37NB";
$regex = '~^'.$key.'-.*\.((jpg)|(png)|(gif))$~';
$files = $files = preg_grep($regex, scandir("../temp/"));
```

Comment: There is a difference between `-` and `_`. Check your regex!

Comment: @arkascha comment solved your answer.

Comment: Sure, I will add an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between - and _. Check your regex and modify it slightly:

```
$regex = '~^'.$key.'_.*\.((jpg)|(png)|(gif))$~';
```